# How to disable scroll wheel in Vim

Tags: vim

I am using Vim 7.3.829 on Windows 7, how can I disable the scroll wheel completely in the settings of Vim?

Comment: Try `:set mouse=`

Comment: The scroll wheel is hard-coded on Windows, so you cannot map it and 'set mouse' does nothing I've discovered.

Comment: On every platform, `set mouse` affects only pointing and clicking, not the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You can unmap these,

```
   :map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
   :map <S-ScrollWheelUp> <C-U>
   :map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-E>
   :map <S-ScrollWheelDown> <C-D>
```

Ref: vimdoc [Scrolling with a mouse wheel](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-mouse-wheel).

There should also be a single configuration, but I can't seem to locate it at this time.

Comment: Upvoted this for the doc link, but note that people actually want the *opposite* of the commands shown here: they should remap these to `<nop>` [as shown in the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/611121/55097).

Answer (score 3):

You need to map the various scroll wheel events to `<nop>`:

```
:nmap <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
:nmap <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
:nmap <C-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
:nmap <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
:nmap <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
:nmap <C-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
:nmap <ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
:nmap <S-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
:nmap <C-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
:nmap <ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
:nmap <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
:nmap <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
```

Then copy and paste those lines and change "nmap" to "imap", and then do it again for "vmap".

See:

```
:help scroll-mouse-wheel
:help <nop>
```

And if you are unfamiliar with mappings:

```
:help map.txt
```